# Getting cart subtotal on WooCommerce Hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this code below in my function.php, and I am trying to get cart subtotal and tax separately. Now using `get_taxes_total()` I am getting `0.4983` as **float**; but using `get_cart_subtotal()` I am getting `£2.49` as **string** and I cannot process it with the TAX. Product's price including tax is `2.99`.

So can anyone please tell me if there is any other Woocommerce function I can use to get cart's subtotal in float rather string.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'process_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
function process_shipping_rate( $rates, $package )
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_total_exc_vat = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    $cart_total_vat = $woocommerce->cart->get_taxes_total(false,false);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried : $subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . number_format(floatval($subtotal), 2, '.', '');

Comment: Hi Rahul It doesn't work as the price comes in string format and is displayed   like this <span class="amount">£2.49</span> in page source and the tax is just displayed as float 0.4983 without any currency sign or div around